# I can not answer f) Pareto efficiency

Tags: microeconomics

> Consider a society of individuals who receive an income of \$10, 000 pesos if they are healthy and \$100 pesos if they are sick. There are two types of individuals: some who get sick with a probability of p and others who are sick with probability of p′ bigger than p. There are equal numbers of
>   individuals of each type in the population. All individuals are CRRA expected utility maximizers
>   with the relative risk-aversion coefficient equal to 1
>
> a) supposing insurance companies can observe the agents’ types, what are the actuarially fair
>   rates they would charge each type for insurance?

a) R1= p, R2=p´

> b) supposing insurance companies can’t observe the types, what would be the actuarially fair rate
>   they would charge if every individual were obliged to buy insurance ?

b) R=1/2p+1/2p´

> c) if only full insurance is available, which agents would insure at the rate in (b)? Does your
>   answer depend on the probabilities of being sick?

c) Individuals who are sick because they have p´bigger than p

> d) given your answer in (c), would the insurance companies be willing to offer such a rate if
>   individuals were free to choose, whether to buy insurance or not?

d) No, because they only attract sick customers.

> e) if an insurance company could offer people who choose not to be insured in (c) a partial insurance contract, can it profitably do so? What is the most insurance that can be offered.

e) By incentive compatibility constraint

> f) is your answer in (e) Pareto efficient? If not, could the inefficiency be resolved by forcing
>   everybody to buy insurance? Explain

I can not answer f) Pareto efficiency

Comment: Why don't you show us what you have done so far?

Comment: a) R1= p,  R2=p´       b) R=1/2p+1/2p´      c) Individuals who are sick  because they have p´bigger than p          d) No, because they only attrack sick customers.     e) By incentive compatibility constraint